# A general question about pointers and dynamic memory

Tags: c++, vector, heap-memory, stack-memory

I'm currently dealing with total of 21 megabytes of plain text data that is written onto several files. It consists of some strings and integers. Containing them properly is important for me to be able to loop through them in various ways so I'm using a fairly complex `typedef` for my container such as

```
typedef std::tuple<std::string,
                   std::array<time_t, 12>,
                   std::array<std::map<std::vector<UINT>, bool>, 4>> cont;
```

I put my data into a `std::vector<cont*> v` at final step. Is my usage logically feasible? I once read that OS reserves 1 megabyte of memory for each executable's stack memory. Is it true? Let's suppose that my data drastically increased. Pointers such as these in my system are 8 bytes by size no matter what they point to. It makes sense since they're just some sort of integers pointing to somewhere in memory and they could be considered as plain `long long int`. Now assuming that stack memory is 1 megabyte and inserting 131072 pointers into this vector could fill it up since the vector itself is allocated in the stack. So what is the correct approach for such an abstract scenario? Would, allocating this vector itself too in the heap, suffice? I mean something like `typedef std::vector<cont*> cont2; cont2* v=new cont2{};`
Now can I access the elements as usual? How is the correct syntax for that?

Comment: sorry for bad wording, removed comments. This question is low quality too, because it is too broad. I am trying to help you

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I put like 45 minutes of effort into this, revised multiple times and this is the best output that comes out of me. I sincerely don't know how else to improve...

Comment: better focus on one thing for one question.Most of the time it is better to split questions into several question even when they are related

Comment: ask one specifc question, not 4. Often you already implicitly get the answer to your other questions by asking one question and getting an answer for that one question

Comment: Yes the default stacksize per thread is usually about 1Mb. Note that `std::string` for strings larger than small-string-optimization is on the heap. `std::map`s data is on the heap. `std::vector`s data is on the heap.  Also please focus on one-question-per Question; please read [ask] or you risk getting down-voted

Comment: take for example 1). This is completely decoupled from the other questions. To answer that we dont need to consider 2,3 and 4, also I am certain that an answer already exists for 1. What should we do now? I could search for a duplciate question for 1) that has an answer and close your question. ( I won't do that, just trying to explain the issue)

Comment: fwiw, trying to work around rules and restrictions by writing more low quality questions will not help to improve your situation.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I see, you're right. Thank you for explaining kindly. Then my question 4 remains. If we are to `push_back` more than 131072 pointers to a `std::vector`, should we allocate the vector itself too in the heap?

Comment: How about removing everything but 4) and concentrate on that?

Comment: @user814412 the data in the vector is on the heap - the vector control block does not  change size when you `push_back`

Comment: Aside: "Also I don't use struct or class because I need to be able to use multiple-level nested loops and every depth of data needs to be looped through somewhere and accessing necessary parts of data is easier with indices only." You can write `operator[]` and `begin` / `end` for a class. That allows you to give meaningful names to things. These multi-level nested loops should be split into member functions of these classes.

Comment: At the very least, you can use type aliases to give meaningful names to things like `std::map<std::vector<UINT>, bool>`

Comment: hum, two things were coming together here: I tried to explain what can be improved on the question and at the same time someone considered the question answerable and wrote an answer that you accepted. I still stand by what I wrote, though once you got an answer you shouldnt modify the question to ask for something else. Imho not wasting effort of an answerer is above any nitpicks about quality. I will roll back your edit so that the answer still makes sense

Comment: dont get me wrong, I am just a regular user who has to be reminded of rules often enough. I think that is something you have to get straight with Quimby, as its their answer that gets invalidated by editing your question. I would just leave it be (contrary to folklore there arent users running around wildly downvoting and closing questions just because afaik)

Comment: @user814412 honestly, I see more often users complaining about others running around wildly and downvoting and closing questions just because, than actually users doing that. And imho that is part of the problem. As a matter of fact we cannot know who voted or why and that is good (my opinion, but anyhow thats just how it is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now assuming that stack memory is 1 megabyte and inserting 131072 pointers into this vector could fill it up since the vector itself is allocated in the stack.

That is false. The vector variable itself is on the stack, but not its elements. `sizeof(vector)` is roughly 3 pointers, no matter what it contains. The backing array is always on the heap. So feel free to store the elements by value - `std::vector<cont>`. All resizable STL containers use heap.

Overall I would not worry about stack in non-embedded environments too much. Using `char buffer[256]` as a scratch space is fine. On the other hand don't put stuff on the stack just because you are worried about dynamic allocation overhead.